# SqlDataSource strange behaviour

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, t-sql, sqldatasource

For the life of me, I can't understand this problem. Basically, I have a `SqlDataSource` which is refusing to return data if there are ANY select parameters. For instance;

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSubscriptions" runat="server"
    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Description FROM Subscription.[Subscriptions">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Int32" Direction="Input" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The above does not work. If I remove the `SelectParameters`, it does work.

In my actual web site, the UserID parameter *is* used. I arrived at the above code after reducing it to find the problem.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `SelectCommand` contains no parameters, you should not specify any `SelectParameters`.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference in this case - if I add 'WHERE @UserID IS NULL OR @UserID IS NOT NULL' it still doesn't work.